# Searching on Concat string not worknig

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that i use for searching customer's last names wich is working fine:

```
SELECT `pt_bookings`.`booking_id`,`pt_bookings`.`booking_date`,
pt_bookings.booking_ref_no, `ai_last_name`,`pt_bookings`.`booking_checkout`,`pt_bookings`.`booking_checkin` FROM (`pt_bookings`) INNER join pt_accounts on pt_accounts.accounts_id = pt_bookings.accounts_id AND pt_accounts.accounts_type='customers'WHERE ai_last_name LIKE CONCAT('%jansen%')
```

But i woul like to search on a string of 3 concatenated varchars ai_firstname ai_middle_name ai_last_name and i would prefere to use this query but it returnes 0 records and does not trough any error. What is wrong about this query? Txs !

```
SELECT `pt_bookings`.`booking_id`,`pt_bookings`.`booking_date`,  pt_bookings.booking_ref_no, CONCAT(`pt_accounts`.`ai_first_name`,`pt_accounts`.`ai_middle_name`,`pt_accounts`.`ai_last_name`) as customer_name,  `pt_bookings`.`booking_checkout`,`pt_bookings`.`booking_checkin`FROM (`pt_bookings`) INNER join pt_accounts on pt_accounts.accounts_id = pt_bookings.accounts_id AND pt_accounts.accounts_type='customers'WHERE  customer_name LIKE  CONCAT('%jansen%')
```

Comment: excuse me but i don't know yet how to make a nice code block

Comment: highlight code in editor, hit `{}` key, or hit ctrl-k.

Comment: I think you get an error that is doesn't recognize customer_name?

Comment: Form has one field for name but there are 3 fields in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT b.`booking_id`, b.`booking_date`,  b.booking_ref_no, 
       CONCAT(`a.`ai_first_name`, a.`ai_middle_name`, a.`ai_last_name`) as customer_name,
      b.`booking_checkout`, b.`booking_checkin`
FROM pt_bookings b INNER join
     pt_accounts a
     on a.accounts_id = b.accounts_id AND
        a.accounts_type = 'customers'
WHERE customer_name LIKE  CONCAT('%jansen%');
```

The main problem is that `customer_name` is a column alias, so you cannot use it in a `WHERE`.  MySQL has a convenient extension, that allows this logic in a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING customer_name LIKE '%jansen%'
```

I'm not sure what the `CONCAT()` is for.  There is no reason to use it with one argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT b.`booking_id`, b.`booking_date`,  b.booking_ref_no, 
       CONCAT(`a.`ai_first_name`, a.`ai_middle_name`, a.`ai_last_name`) as customer_name,
      b.`booking_checkout`, b.`booking_checkin`
FROM pt_bookings b INNER join
     pt_accounts a
     on a.accounts_id = b.accounts_id AND
        a.accounts_type = 'customers'
WHERE
  CONCAT(ai_firstname, ai_middle_name, ai_last_name)
  LIKE '%jansen%';
```